# How to get date and time in Angular 4,5,6 and above using DatePipe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date, date-pipe

I am working in an angular 4 application, Here I need to get the current `Date and Time Using` angular `DatePipe`.

I want to get the date and time in the following format

**dd-mm-yyyy  hh:MM:ss AM/PM**

I got the expected by using the Angular DatePipe as follows

```
<p>{{today | date:'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a':'+0530'}}</p>
```

output :

```
10-05-2018 03:28:57 PM
```

Here I What I want to do is get the same output from my app.component.ts without touching the HTML's

So I tried the below code but it generates a 13 digit timestamp

```
today = Date.now();
    fixedTimezone = this.today;
```

SO how can I get the date and time as the mentioned format purely from app.component.ts file without using HTML's.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
let dateFormat = require('dateformat');
let now = new Date();
dateFormat(now, "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT");
```

---

```
Thursday, May 10th, 2018, 7:11:21 AM
```

---

And this format is exactly like your question

```
dateFormat(now, "dd, mm, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT");
```

returns `10, 05, 2018 7:26:57 PM`

you need npm package `npm i dateformat`
here is a link for the npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat

Here is another question that inspires me [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

---

`h:MM:ss TT` results `7:26:57 PM`

`HH:MM:ss` results `13:26:57`

### Here is it https://jsfiddle.net/5z1tLspw/

I hope that helps.

Comment: I hv editted my answer. You need to install the dateformat package. That is why you are getting such error.

Comment: Expected is 12 hour time format "10-05-2018  03:45:12 PM"

Comment: @Nikson check it out now. U can use 12 or 24 hr option with simple trick.

Comment: How can I see the output of your code using console ?

Comment: get_Date_Time(){
        let dateFormat = require('dateformat');
        let now = new Date();
        dateFormat(now, "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT");
        console.log("date :" + dateFormat );
    }

Comment: Is it right ? Because in console it returns lot of codes only not date and time

Comment: @Nikson tell me if that did not fix it.

Comment: Man at the end of the code there is an alert code you can change that to console.log or anything you want.

Next the code use today's date so you can pass the date you get from API.

So now I think you can change a date to a format you need. Gud day.

Answer (score 28):

**Will works on *Angular 6* or above**

You don't need any 3rd party library. You can format using angular `method/util`. import `formatDate` from the common package and pass other data. See the below-given example.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {formatDate } from '@angular/common';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  today= new Date();
  jstoday = '';
  constructor() {
    this.jstoday = formatDate(this.today, 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a', 'en-US', '+0530');
  }
}
```

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vjosat?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: got the error like "has no exported member 'formatdate'" in 
import {formatDate } from '@angular/common';

Comment: Yes it is not exposed below angular 6 :( It will come with angular 6. Check if u can upgrade. or use moment or dateformat
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20536

Answer (score 1):

Uses the function formatDate to format a date according to locale rules.

```
{{ value_expression | date [ : format [ : timezone [ : locale ] ] ] }}
```

It may be useful:)

Answer (score 0):

To get formatted date in Angular we can use Angular Datepipe.

For an example we can use following code to get formatted date in our code.

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-name-class',
    templateUrl: './name.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./name.component.scss']
})

export class NameComponent implements OnInit {
  
  // define datepipe

  datePipe: DatePipe = new DatePipe('en-US');
  
  constructor(){}

  // method to get formatted date

  getFormattedDate(){
    
    var date = new Date();
    var transformDate = this.datePipe.transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    return transformDate;

  }
}
```

After that you can user `getFormattedDate()` method inside your `html` code.

```
<p>{{getFormattedDate()}}</p>
```