# How to format material datepicker date value to "MM-DD-YYY" format in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I am trying to format below date to following format MM-DD-YYYY in Angular 6. I had a look at simpler issues posted in SO and other sites as well but I am unable to resolve it.

I am using Material [Angular DatePicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) component.

Date picker gives me

```
Thu Oct 25 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (Gulf Standard Time)
```

I want to format it to

```
MM-DD-YYYY
```

My code

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [min]="minDate" [matDatepicker]="date" [(ngModel)]="request.date | request.date: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a'" placeholder="Choose a date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="date"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #date></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

I also tried with DatePipe module like below but nothing works

```
this.datePipe.transform(this.request.date,"MM-DD-YYYY")
```

Comment: Do you want to display in `MM-DD-YYYY` format or in ts?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Thanks I need the output value to be in MM-DD-YYYY to send the value to the backend

Comment: have you searched for `datepipe`?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I tried with that but nothing works in my case

Comment: Typo  --> this.datePipe.transform(this.request.date,"MM-dd-yyyy")

Comment: Expected format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) to format the date as per your requirement.

Import in main.module.ts

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
```

and add `Datapipe` in Providers array.

Then in related component import the same as

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
```

and in constructor

```
constructor(private datePipe : DatePipe)
{

}
```

and to use date pipe just use

```
this.datePipe.transform(your_date, 'MM-dd-yyyy');
```

Have a look at [StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2kgwqe) where I have consoled the date value in `MM-dd-yyyy` format.

Comment: This one worked but I had to set the format like this.datePipe.transform(this.request.date, "MM-dd-yyyy")

Answer (score 1):

Use the `dateformat` function from angular common.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50270330/how-to-get-date-and-time-in-angular-4-using-datepipe) answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the component you are using mat-datepicker

> import { DateAdapter } from '@angular/material';
>
> constructor(private dateAdapter: DateAdapter) {
>   this.dateAdapter.setLocale('your locale'); }

Answer (score 0):

```
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';

formatDate(date, 'MMM, yyyy', 'en-US');
```

Angular 9